# ResultSet how to put it into a ArrayList

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Is "ResultSet" considered to be an ArrayList? I'm talking about jdbc.  If no, then
how do I put the information i get from my DB using the

```
while (result.next()) {
....

}
```

syntax into an ArrayList called something like hotelResult?

I hope it was understandable.

Comment: You do the hardwork: build it by hand

Comment: Just iterate on your ResultSet and add all elements to your ArrayList.

Comment: Well... I'm not sure how it's done. I'm a newbie at java. 

Let's say I want to add hotelNo into my ArrayList.. What syntax do I use? I really don't know :/

Thanks for quick answer! :)

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) might be helpful. The only super-interfaces listed are `Autocloseable` and `Wrapper`, whereas an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has an entirely different list of interfaces. (Check out `ArrayList.add`) So in other words, no, a ResultSet is not an array list. Here's a [reasonable example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/resultset.html).

Comment: If you were asking the syntax of adding to your arraylist: hotelResult.add()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, ResultSet is not considered an ArrayList but rather a table.
If hotelResult for example has the type of String you can fill the list with this piece of code(if the column from the ResultSet is a String).

```
while(result.next()) {
  hotelResult.add(result.getString("Enter the columnname here");
}
```

For each datatype there is a method to get the value from the ResultSet.
Look in the Java API for the different kinds of methods.

Comment: Okay I think I got it. 

Well.. Now I got another problem. I was assigned by my teacher to put some information from a DB into an ArrayList. I now think I know how to do it if it's only strings, but in my case i have String, Int and (var)Char. How do I possibly put that information into a single Arraylist?

Comment: @AdemÖkmen Create an object with properties for the information, create an object for a row in the `ResultSet`, and add it to the list.

Comment: Yes, exactly like Mark Rotteveel said. Create a class called HotelData, in the HotelData class create variables of the String and int. For as far i can tell is varchar is the same as String :)!

Comment: @AdemÖkmen See my post under Michael M's post.

Answer (score 16):

A ResultSet is not an ArrayList.  Rather, it is a special object (Interface) to hold data retrieved by queries via JDBC connections.

A ResultSet object cannot be updated, and can only be traversed forward... not back.  By default, you can only iterate through it once, from the first row to the last (though with a bit of coding, you can generate a ResultSet object that can be edited and traversed bi-directionally).

The records stored within a ResultSet object can easily be placed within an ArrayList.  Here is an example on how you can do this:

```
Connection con = ... ;
Statement stmt = ... ;
ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("..."); 

//Stores properties of a ResultSet object, including column count
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = results.getMetaData(); 
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

ArrayList<String> hotelResultList = new ArrayList<>(columnCount); 
while (results.next()) {              
   int i = 1;
   while(i <= columnCount) {
        hotelResultList.add(results.getString(i++));
   }
}
```

NOTE: This example assumes a single String being returned in the query, such as a Hotel name.  You will likely want to hold multiple pieces of data about each hotel, in which case you would create a "Hotel" object, and then create the ArrayList as a List of Hotel objects. By using a rowmapper, each hotel object can be populated with the associated data.

In addition, using one of the popular JDBC frameworks to handle JDBC connections, queries, and result sets can simplify the process further.

Comment: Thanks this was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I will help u out :)! 
Create the needed variables in the class see my example :)

```
public class HotelData {
    private String hotelName = null;
    private int hotelTelephone = 0;

    public HotelData(String hotelName, int hotelTelephone) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
    this.hotelTelephone = hotelTelephone;
    }
}
```

Now create the ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<HotelData> hotelResult = new ArrayList<HotelData>();
```

With the while method now:

```
while(result.next()) {
    hotelResult.add(new HotelData(result.getString("Enter columnname"), result.getInt("Enter colummname")));
}
```

Hope this will help u buddy :)! If u need to get the data from the ArrayList u can simply write ur own get methods in the HotelData class!

Comment: Ah lovely. Thanks a lot! Just one question: I got it to work without the hotelData class? Why do we need it? I did this: 




 <code> ArrayList<String> hotelInfo = new ArrayList<String>(); while(result.next()) { hotelInfo.add(result.getString("hotelNo")); // how come it works when it's an INT not a STRING?? hotelInfo.add(result.getString("hotelName")); hotelInfo.add(result.getString("city")); System.out.println(hotelInfo); }  </code>

edit again: Sorry. I don't know how to format the code so it looks good here

Comment: See my new post in this topic ;)

Answer (score 1):

i believe that will clear- ArrayList hotels holds objects of HotelDtos

```
public class HotelDto {
private String hotelName;
private String hotelAddress;

private int hotelRank;

public String getHotelName() {
    return hotelName;
}

public void setHotelName(String hotelName) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
}

public String getHotelAddress() {
    return hotelAddress;
}

public void setHotelAddress(String hotelAddress) {
    this.hotelAddress = hotelAddress;
}

public int getHotelRank() {
    return hotelRank;
}

public void setHotelRank(int hotelRank) {
    this.hotelRank = hotelRank;
}
```

}

```
public class HotelDao {

public List<HotelDto> getHotlInfo(String hotelName) {

    List<HotelDto> hotels = new ArrayList<HotelDto>();
    try {

        String query = "SELECT  hotelName, hotelAddress,hotelrank " + "FROM   HOTELS_TABLE "
                + "WHERE hotelName = " + "'" + hotelName + "'" + " ";

        ResultSet resultSet = DBConnection.getDBConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(query);

        int i = 0;

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            HotelDto hDto = new HotelDto();
            hDto.setHotelName(resultSet.getString(1));
            hDto.setHotelAddress(resultSet.getString(2));
            hDto.setHotelrank(resultSet.getInt(3));
            hotels.add(i, hDto);
            i++;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return hotels;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, u don't really need the HotelData class.
The only thing this class does is holding the data nice and clean in one Object (for each specific hotel).

If you implement it your way, you must cast all the values to Strings first(if they do not contain String values) before u can store your items in the hotelInfo list. This is because the hotelInfo list has the String type, in my implementation this is also not needed(the casts) because i have created a constructor with one String value and one int value.

If u want your example to work implement it like this:

not this: hotelInfo.add(result.getString("hotelNo"));

but like this: hotelInfo.add("" + result.getInt("hotelNo")); //Notice the cast here!

Comment: Thank you for all of your replies. It really means a lot to me :) 

Okay, so I tried your way including the cast, but it says "cannot cast from int to String"

If I do it "my" way, however, then I actually am able to print it all out into the console properly. It even includes the integer. 
So I think it is working (at least for now, still need a lot of work in this project). 

I will not bother you anymore. I'd like to thank you for your help. It's getting late, so I need to sleep. Might be back tomorrow with a new question hehe.

Comment: Adem, i got the fix for you i made a mistake: do it like this: hotelInfo.add("" + result.getInt("hotelNo")); Instead of the one with the cast!

Comment: See this comment above, and i have edited my last answer too with the correct solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how I can get the database values which is added in my list .Here is the solution below

1. pom.xml file add below snippet of dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
       <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
       <version>18.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. call the method from the main program .

   ```
   List output =  readRows(rs);
   ```

   here `rs` is the `ResultSet` object, `readRows()` is the method
3. below is the code snippet for the `readRows()` method

   ```
   private static List<List<Object>> readRows(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
   {
       ImmutableList.Builder<List<Object>> rows = ImmutableList.builder();
       int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
       while (rs.next()) {
           List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
           for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
               row.add(rs.getObject(i));
           }
           rows.add(row);
       }
       return rows.build();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to complete above technical solution with performance tuning advice.

Everyone didn't mention performance implication when storing entire SELECT output into program level variable in Java (applicable to any programming language).

Commercial DB size has growth to 1TB easily, and a single table is normal to be 300GB.  iPhone 14 with 512GB is available today as well, in case you think 300GB of data is unlikely for the output of the SELECT statement.

Putting the table size of 1TB in mind, storing the entire SELECT output into simple variable like array, will indirectly used up 1TB of RAM.  In Java, that is consider Java heap memory.

Certainly they are members who suggest storing the data in array of HotelDao class which contains setHotelName(), getHotelName(), etc.  This might double its Java internal memory usage from 1TB to 2TB.

Running any Java application, you have to specify its heap memory with Java parameter -Xmx (assuming only heap memory involve) during application startup.  If you are hosting it in J2EE, then it could be Apache Tomcat startup, IBM WebSphere Application Server startup, JBoss, etc.  If you are doing it via reporting server, e.g. Cognos, Informatica, then they have their own configuration to define -Xmx parameter.

Next, multi-user, multi-instance, concurrent access is norm in today's technology. If multiple users are trigger from GUI to request to run the same SELECT statement concurrently, e.g. flight booking system, reporting, then there will be multiple instance of the same SELECT with 1TB table size, and minimum 1TB Java array variable size in Java heap memory.  Imagine 10 concurrent users, such as Expedia, will easily created 10 of such array variable, each of 1TB.  The total variable size will be 10TB, if there is only 1 such SELECT-Array design in the entire program.

The problem here it is impractical to define 2TB of Java heap memory during Java application startup.  Configures 10TB Java heap memory is way beyond the hardware limitation of today's RAM max size, unless you are looking for heavy paging to the OS swap memory area.

Neither Eclipse Temurin nor Oracle Java 19 document the default max heap size (-Xmx) anymore, but Eclipse Java 9 (https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/openj9_defaults/) indicated the default is 25% RAM size. In other word, 128GB RAM machine will allocate 32GB.  Either value will not even fit 1TB, and immediately the entire Java application crashed once it fully used up 32GB (default), or entire RAM, 128GB.

Certainly Windows admin will tell you Windows will auto tune its pagefile as needed.  My question will be how poor will be business users' experience when finding a hotel in Expedia takes minutes.  Even Windows allow to allocate 10TB pagefile, we have to consider overall application performance (end user experience) degradation with the trade off of OS paging to disk; due to Java application programmer storing entire SELECT output in local variable, and even bigger if stored as Java class object.

In entire StackOverflow.com, it is often members do not consider application performance when designing JDBC application, and consider about volume size.  The latest Intel workstation single socket CPU can only accommodate **128GB RAM DDR4** (ref Xeon E-2388G). I have not see any programmer who have access to **1TB RAM** top end server, even that can't handle Java application that need 10TB RAM due to this design

Note: Latest Intel desktop CPU Core i9 14th gen that supports DDR5 - max RAM size 128GB RAM today (2022-10). Ref [www.crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com)